# Implementing Processor Core for Cache Module in Verilog

Tags: verilog, memory, computer-architecture, cache, tag

I have written a simulation module for a Direct Mapped Cache (consisting of data, tag, and valid rams and cache controller) in Verilog. I now want to implement a Processor Core/Driver (also in Verilog) which will provide read, write and other instructions to the Cache Module for reading/writing data. I'd be thankful for providing any help in implementing this processor module as I have no clue where and how to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Visit and join over at [OpenCores](http://opencores.org/). There is a section there of various types of CPU cores that can be plugged into an FPGA design.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~milom/cis371-Spring13/lab/lab3/

This could helps you for your problem

Comment: You might want to expand on that answer.  A link with no explanation isn't much help.